# Why useState provided state is not getting updated in some particular scenarios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have been through many similar QnAs on StackOverflow but I am still confused about why it does not work for me. I understand that state update is not synchronous. Also I am not performing any DOM manipulation.

The full working demo here which demonstrates the issue - https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-pine-kljujf?file=/src/Tabs.js

In this example I am rendering few tabs. A new tab initially presents a list of DB "table" names (which is fixed for this demo). On selecting the table name, the list is replaced by table's content.

[image: Initial state]

The issue is when you close an open tab the `currentTab` state does not update to the (open) tab I am setting to. Because of which the tab's detail area remains blank until I manually click on an open tab's name.

[image: After closing the third tab]

In the above picture I closed the third tab. The expectation was that the tab selection should have auto changed to second tab, but it did not. The code for that same is as below.

```
  function removeTab(id) {
    const ntl = tabsList;
    const idx = ntl.findIndex((v) => v.id === id);
    if (idx !== -1) {
      ntl.splice(idx, 1);
      if (ntl.length) {
        let t = ntl[idx];
        console.log("------", t, idx);
        if (!t) {
          t = ntl[0];
        }
        console.log("++++++1", t, t.id);
        setCurrentTab(t.id);
        setTabsList([...ntl]);
      } else {
        const t = newTab();
        console.log("++++++2", t, t.id);
        setCurrentTab(t.id);
        setTabsList([t]);
      }
    }
  }
```

Above the passed `id` was that of the third tab. The `tabsList` state contains an array with data of each tab. `currentTab` contains only the `id` of the current tab. As per the `console.log` statements above the correct tab's `id` is passed, but the currentTab never updates. Even if I put a code like below.

```
useEffect(() => { console.log('------------>', currentTab) }, [currentTab]);
```

It never fires in this case.

The `removeTab` method is invoked from JSX like below.

```
{tabsList.map((t) => (
          <a
            key={t.id + ""}
            className={
              "tab tab-bordered " + (currentTab === t.id ? "tab-active" : "")
            }
            onClick={() => {
              setCurrentTab(t.id);
            }}
          >
            {t.name}
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                removeTab(t.id); // On clicking X button we remove tab
              }}
            >
              X
            </button>
          </a>
        ))}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems

- Splice is mutating state directly, to prevent this, you can use spread operator to make a copy of array.
- 2ndly, The Button is inside Anchor Tag and both have onClick, So when the cross button is clicked, Parent anchor onclick is also called, To prevent this, you can do e.stopPropagation().

Here is the edits i made to the codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-platform-dvkxrq?file=/src/Tabs.js:3723-3738

Comment: You are my hero! In my initial version I did create a copy of array before mutating, but the issue persisted. The main issue was the click event bubble. It totally escaped my eye. Sometimes the issue is far simpler than we think.

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes to the code they may help you finding a better solution

Setting the initial values tab in state instead of useEffect, [to reduce a render cycles](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#updating-state-based-on-props-or-state)

[Creating a new array](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-arrays-in-state#removing-from-an-array) on delete and add

you can find the [modified codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-cherry-ejmmqd)

Using a single selected item to render the content [to prevent duplication](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/choosing-the-state-structure#avoid-duplication-in-state)

the only issue was react was not flushing the changes on delete, so I had to use a hack, which you may find helpful in such cases

```
let tabId = 1;

const DisplayTable = ({ isNewMode, name, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {isNewMode ? (
        <TableSelection {...rest} />
      ) : (
        <div>Contents of table: {name}</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default function Tabs() {
  const [tabsList, setTabsList] = useState([
    {
      id: tabId,
      name: "Select table",
      isNewMode: true
    }
  ]);
  const [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = useState(tabId);

  function newTab() {
    tabId = tabId + 1; // unique id check
    return {
      id: tabId,
      name: "Select table",
      isNewMode: true
    };
  }

  function addTab() {
    const t = newTab();
    setTabsList((tabs) => [...tabs, t]);
    console.log("++++++3", t, t.id);
    setCurrentTab(t.id);
  }

  async function removeTab(id) {

    //  functional updaters are simpler
    //  setTabsList(tabs => [...tabs.filter((a) => a.id !== id)])


    // need better logic to select the right tab, this seems simeple enough to understand
    const deleteIndex = tabsList.findIndex((v) => v.id === id);
    // 
    if (deleteIndex !== -1) {
      const filteredItems = tabsList.filter((a) => a.id !== id);

      if (deleteIndex > 0) {
        const prevId = filteredItems[deleteIndex - 1];
        console.log("prevId", prevId);

        setTabsList([...filteredItems]);
        await Promise.resolve();
        setCurrentTab(prevId.id);
      }
    }
  }

  const selectedItem = tabsList?.find((item) => item.id === currentTab);

  // console.log("Rendering......", currentTab, tabsList);
  return (
    <div className="p-8 h-full flex flex-col">
      <div className="tabs">
        {tabsList.map((t) => (
          <a
            href="#"
            key={t.id}
            className={
              "tab tab-bordered " + (currentTab === t.id ? "tab-active" : "")
            }
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              setCurrentTab(t.id);
            }}
          >
            {t.name}
            <button
              className="ml-2 btn btn-ghost btn-square btn-xs"
              onClick={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                removeTab(t.id);
              }}
            >
              X
            </button>
          </a>
        ))}
        <a href="#" className="tab">
          <button
            className="btn btn-ghost btn-square btn-xs"
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              addTab();
            }}
          >
            +
          </button>
        </a>
      </div>
      {selectedItem ? (
        <DisplayTable
          onTableSelection={(item) => {
            tabId = tabId + 1;
            const d = { ...item, id: tabId, isNewMode: false };
            setTabsList((t) => [...t, d]);
            console.log("table select", d);
            setCurrentTab(d.id);
          }}
          {...selectedItem}
        />
      ) : null}
      {/* {tabsList.map((t) => (
        <div key={t.id}>
          <TableSelection />
        </div>
      ))} */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hope is helps in some way,

Cheers